# j2pkcs11.dll 64-bit version

Tags: java, dll, 32bit-64bit, pkcs#11

Here is my problem:

I want to use `j2pkcs11.dll` in my java application. I downloaded dll from [here](http://originaldll.com/file/j2pkcs11.dll/18741.html) and move it to system32 directory. When I run my code I have got :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\j2pkcs11.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

My OS is windows 7 64-bit and my jre is 64-bit too. Obviously I need to get 64-bit version of `j2pkcs11.dll` but when I searched the web I could not find it anywhere. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those who may encounter this problem, it seems that there is no support for j2pkcs11 in jre-64bit. So I install 32-bit jre and select this jre as my runtime jre in Intellij.

Comment: It's true only for Java ealier than 7. In Java 8 you have this dll. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640506/using-j2pkcs11-dll-with-java-8-64-bit-on-windows-7-64-bit)