# Using j2pkcs11.dll with java 8 (64-bit) on windows 7 (64-bit)

Tags: pkcs#11

I trying to use the j2pkcs11.dll (packaged with jdk1.8.0 - 64bit) to access certificates stored on a smartcard but not unable to make it work.

--- sample code to add the SunPKCS11 provider dynamically ---

```
    String pkcs11ConfigSettings = "name = " + "TestSmartCard" + "\n" + "library = " + "C:/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/bin/j2pkcs11.dll";
    byte[] pkcs11ConfigBytes = pkcs11ConfigSettings.getBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream confStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11ConfigBytes);            
    Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(confStream);
```

---- the exception I get ---

```
java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:376)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:103)
    at scpoc.SmartCard.main(SmartCard.java:28)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: The specified procedure could not be found.
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.connect(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.<init>(PKCS11.java:138)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.getInstance(PKCS11.java:151)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:313)
```

---

JEP 131 claims to have PKCS11 support in Java 8 (http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/131) but I have not been able to get it to work on windows 7 using the java8 64-bit. Note: I also tried the java 8 32-bit on windows 7 - but no luck either.

Has anyone had any success using the SunPKCS11 provider with java 8 (Windows 7)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SunPKCS11 provider is present only in 32-bit Windows version of JRE up until JRE7. Since JRE8 it is present also in 64-bit Windows version of JRE. This is the information you see in [JEP131](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/131).

If you need to use PKCS#11 API in 64-bit Windows version of JRE older than JRE8 then you will have to use one of alternative 3rd party implementations - such as [IAIK-JCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAIK-JCE).

I have also noticed in your code sample that you are trying to directly use "j2pkcs11.dll" as a PKCS#11 library which is wrong because it is just a JNI wrapper sitting between JRE and the library implementing PKCS#11 interface. Instead of loading "j2pkcs11.dll" you need to load PKCS#11 library provided by your smartcard or HSM vendor.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. PKCS#11 module (j2pcks11.dll) packaged with JRE8-64 bit running on Windows 7 (64-bit) does not work for me. It's look like a bug to me.

Comment: @vince I have updated my answer. Please take a look at third paragraph.

Comment: You are correct, My rookie mistake. Since my smartcard reader does not provide a PKCS11 module - I mistakenly thought that j2pkcs11.dll would provide the PKCS11 implementation. I hunted the net and found a compatible module (opensc-pkcs11,dll) that worked out fine now. Thanks again.